# Speech is not recognized via microphone in python speechRecognition module

Tags: python, speech-recognition, microphone

When i run this program the speech is recognized if I use a headset or an external microphone.
But, if I use the laptop microphone( **Microphone Array (Realtek(R) Audio)** ) the speech is not recognized. It's like the program hangs at the line `audio = r.listen(source)` If I say something and then plug in the headset then the program works.
The microphone in the laptop is working perfectly.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening......")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"USER: {query}\n")

    except Exception:
        print("Did not catch that")
```

Why id this happening? Can somebody help me out please?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine with me! Try raising your voice while recording and see if it works

Comment: I'm shouting at the top of my lungs and its not working

Comment: I swear... it works fine with me

Comment: Try increasing your mic's sensitivity

Comment: probably you have to use some variable in `Microphone()` to select which microphone to use - probalby as default it may use external microphone.

Comment: in [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/) you can see `Microphone(device_index = None)` and `A device index is an integer between 0 and pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1 `

Answer (score 3):

`r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)`
I used this function and it's working now.
This increases the range to recognize the audio.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: The site allows me to do that only after 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

I will guess.

Probably it uses external microphone as default device and you have to manually set other device.

In [documentation](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme) you can see

```
Microphone(device_index = None)
```

And

```
A device index is an integer between 0 and pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1
```

You can also see how to get list of all available devices.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
```

---

**BTW:** You can also read [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#troubleshooting) - maybe it gives more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out the MIDI Settings of your Laptop. In macOS this Error is reproducible with the Format "96.000 Hz" in the MIDI Application (which every Macbook has) under the device "Macbook Microphone"

Comment: Hello, please add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.