# Speech Recognition return 'Bad Request'

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I use `Speech Recognition` and input raw data via Microphone. And also I use `Recognizer_google` to do speech to text. But it return an error called `Bad Request`.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

and the error is:

```
Say something!
Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; recognition request failed: Bad Request
```

Comment: Take a look at this,
[python speech recognition](https://www.codegrepper.com/profile/prathamesh-bhatkar) answer. Maybe you need to specify the language in your request or you miss a different thing!

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin hi, thank you for responding. But I have specific the language and it still return the same error

Comment: I have tested it on Mac and it runs without any problems. Make sure that you can open and use your microphone ports!

Comment: SEE THIS [speech-is-not-recognized-via-microphone-in-python-speechrecognition-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373831/speech-is-not-recognized-via-microphone-in-python-speechrecognition-module)